# No inject registered. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules

Tags: android, dagger, mortar

Hi I'm new to dagger and trying to study it with simple android app.

I'm getting error from the title even if there is module that injects this view. Could anyone help me figure out why it does not inject view ?

Here is my main module for app:

```
@dagger.Module(injects = {App.class, MainActivity.class}, complete = false)
public class AppModule {
    private final App app;
    public AppModule(App app) { this.app = app; }
    @Provides @Singleton public App provideApp() { return app; }
}
```

another module that injects my view:

```
@Layout(R.layout.sidemenu)
public class SidemenuScreen implements Blueprint{
    @Override public String getMortarScopeName() { return getClass().getName(); }
    @Override public Object getDaggerModule() { return new Module();}

    @dagger.Module(injects= SidemenuView.class, addsTo = AppModule.class)
    public static class Module { 
       public Module() {}
    }

    @Singleton public static class Presenter extends ViewPresenter<SidemenuView> {
        @Inject Presenter() {}
        @Override protected void onLoad(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onLoad(savedInstanceState); }
        @Override protected void onSave(Bundle outState) { super.onSave(outState); }
    }
}
```

As you can see `SidemenuScreen.Module` injects `SidemenuView` and addsTo `AppModule`. Am I wrong ?

ObjectGraph is created like this in `onCreate()` method of my Application class :

```
    ObjectGraph objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new AppModule(this));
    objectGraph.inject(this);
    rootScope = Mortar.createRootScope(BuildConfig.DEBUG, objectGraph);
```

view that should be injected

```
public class SidemenuView extends LinearLayout {
    @Inject SidemenuScreen.Presenter presenter;

    public SidemenuView(Context context) {this(context, null); }
    public SidemenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { this(context, attrs, 0); }
    public SidemenuView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Mortar.inject(context, this);
    }
}
```

and activity that uses all this stuff:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MortarActivityScope activityScope;
    @Inject App app;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Blueprint screen = getScreenFromIntent(getIntent());

        if (screen != null) {
            MortarScope parentScope = Mortar.getScope(getApplication());
            activityScope = Mortar.requireActivityScope(parentScope, screen);
            activityScope.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Mortar.inject(this, this);
        }

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.sidemenu);
    }
}
```

Here used [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) Sliding menu lib:

So when `menu.setMenu(R.layout.sidemenu);` called it inflates view and `Mortar.inject(context, this);` is called from the `SidemenuView` constructor where error occurs.

Here is backstack:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dagger/com.example.dagger.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.example.dagger.ui.sidemenu.SidemenuView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.example.dagger.ui.sidemenu.SidemenuView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:375)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.MainActivity.setupSidemenu(MainActivity.java:93)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:375)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.MainActivity.setupSidemenu(MainActivity.java:93)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.example.dagger.ui.sidemenu.SidemenuView. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.
            at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.getInjectableTypeBinding(ObjectGraph.java:302)
            at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.inject(ObjectGraph.java:279)
            at mortar.Mortar.inject(Mortar.java:93)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.sidemenu.SidemenuView.<init>(SidemenuView.java:29)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.sidemenu.SidemenuView.<init>(SidemenuView.java:21)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:375)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.MainActivity.setupSidemenu(MainActivity.java:93)
            at com.example.dagger.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I removed `addsTo` from submodules, added `complite=false, library=true` to submodules and added `includes` in `AppModule` and now it works. But I still can't get why it did not work as I did it before. The way it is done is a bit inconvenient because each time I implement new module I need to go to `AppModule` and add this module in list of included modules. It breaks an Open/Closed principle so I am still interested if there is a way to add new module with `addsTo=AppModule.class`.

Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not inject **SidemenuView** in your **AppModule**?

Comment: It will be a mess if inject everything in one module. Something like keep all the classes in one package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think I found out why this is happening. With `includes` you add a submodule to the main `AppModule`. With `addsTo` you tell the IDE parser that your submodule extends the `Appmodule` but you need to create a subgraph manually.

I don't know if its enough to just create a new graph from the submodule with `ObjectGraph.create(new Submodule());` and it will automaticly include the parent Module specified with `addsTo`.
If it does't work, you need to manually create a subgraph with `parentGraph.plus(new Submodule())`